# Get list of all words that can be stemmed to a particular stemming

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming

I was wondering if it was possible to get a list of longer words that could be stemmed to the same word. Basically we have a list of stemmed words, and we would like to make a new corpus with all words that could have generated this stemming. For example you can do:

```
import nltk
ps = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()
print(ps.stem('rowing'))
'row'
print(ps.stem('rows'))
'row'
print(ps.stem('rowed'))
'row'
```

In our case we have the word `row` and we like put this in some function and get the list `['rowing','rows', 'rowed']` (this assumes those are the only words that stem to row). Is this implemented in nltk? The hack solution is to just add every common ending to every stemmed word we have, but we would like to avoid doing that. I used PorterStemmer in the example, but if this inverse look up works for any stemmer that would work for us. Thanks!

Comment: Also, adding every common ending can make a few words with a mis-identified or overloaded stem.

Comment: In any case, reverse stemming strongly suggests that you build a reverse-lookup dict (or equivalent structure) from your corpus.  See the duplicate link.